# Date string cannot be parsed into date/time in Google Sheets

Tags: datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an IFTTT integration that writes date strings to a sheet. I'm trying to filter the sheet by days of the week, but in order to do that, I need to be able to convert the date strings into actual dates.

The dates are formatted like this:

`August 12, 2019 at 08:40PM`

But when I feed it into `DATEVALUE`, it cannot parse it. I've tried removing the leading 0 before `08:40PM` and adding a space between the minute and `PM`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "at ".

Use `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"at ",""))
```

[image]

If you need the time portion as well, you can use `TIMEVALUE`:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"at ",""))+TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"at ",""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "at ", ))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Make IFTTT Date Format play nice with Google Spreadsheets in 2020

**Formatted row**

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("{{CompletedDate}}"," at ", " ")) + TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("{{CompletedDate}}"," at ", " ")) ||| {{Title}} ||| {{Notes}}
```

**Out**

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("June 28, 2020 at 01:26PM"," at ", " ")) + TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("June 28, 2020 at 01:26PM"," at ", " "))
```

**Settings:** https://d.pr/i/1AOSL1

**Format**: date and time in table possible configure to your taste, https://d.pr/i/pPDDYN