# Include DATE function into FILTER function

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheet's filter function as below

```
=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, X1),W2:W>=Y1,W2:W<=Z1)
```

where the W column has date info.

To get the W column I process column A with the following function

```
=date(right(A2,4), mid(A2,4,2),left(A2,2))
```

This is because The A column has the date in a format that breaks my filter as shown below.

```
17.06.2023
17.06.2023
16.06.2023
```

Is it possible to insert the Date function into the FILTER function directly. This would mean that I wouldn't have to create the column W.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet/screenshot data for your `filter function` , this will be easier for me to understand and replicate your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the whole picture of your formula specifically your `filter function` but **how about this alternative:**

By using `datevalue` and `substitute` function:

For example: on your given date: `17.06.2023` using `substitute`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A3:A5, ".", "/")
```

this will be `17/06/2023`

then make it serial using `datevalue` which will output a number `45094`,

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A5, ".", "/"))
```

**Assuming that, `Col B` is your `Y1` in this example or your desired criteria
then you may *insert* this directly in the `filter function` like this:**

```
=FILTER(E3:E5,DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A5, ".", "/")) >= B3)
```

RESULT:
[image]

Note/s:

- The Illustrated `filter formula` is not exactly like the posted formula but to show alternative how to insert date in filter function
- `DateValue()` may not recognize date so be careful with this,as the date format is based on the locale setting in your document.

Ref:

[DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en)

[Date string cannot be parsed into date/time in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206220/date-string-cannot-be-parsed-into-date-time-in-google-sheets)

[Sheets not recognizing dates :Error DATEVALUE parameter](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/33346427/sheets-not-recognizing-dates-error-datevalue-parameter-14-2-2020-cannot-be-parsed-to-date-time?hl=en)

Comment: I make sure as well that in my column B, it is formatted as `date` in sheets. Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks @Twilight. The csv I have is a bank generated csv so I can't place a screen capture directly.
Nevertheless I think what you have added might fit the bill. I will give it a go and get back to you.

Also in relation to the range as the first argument in substitute function. Could it be replaced with the more generic A3:A, and similarly can the second argument in the filter function B3 be replaced with B3:B. The number of rows in this bank csv will vary depending on the date range that I download, and it would be great to not have to give a last row index.

Comment: Thanks @Twilight. That solved my problem.

I used 
=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, X1),DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(V2:V,".","/"))>=Y1,DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(V2:V,".","/"))<=Z1)

Answer (score 0):

First convert them into date inside your formula and give it a name. Then filter other columns by comparing that named date ranges with your desired criteria. Try like-

```
=LET(x,INDEX(DATE(RIGHT(A2:A,4),MID(A2:A,4,2),LEFT(A2:A,2))),FILTER(I2:I,x>=F2,x<=G2))
```

[image]